# Does the N material need to be directly touching the P material?

Tags: transistors, diodes, semiconductors

I know a diode works like:

```
anode wire --[ P ][ N ]-- cathode wire
```

Would it also work like so?

```
anode wire --[ P ]-----------[ N ]-- cathode wire
                   junction
                     wire
```

Comment: Look up PIN diodes...

Comment: @BrianDummond Pin diodes still use a semiconductor material for junction. OP wants to put a wire instead

Comment: Wouldn't that create two Schottky diodes?

Comment: It will potentially create one schokky... Not sure if you can make a  Schottky with the other dopant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work as a PN diode if you separate the elements. For a PN diode to operate normally, you have to be able to inject carriers from one material (e.g. electrons from the n-type and holes from the p-type) directly into the opposite polarity region. With just wires on the semiconductor, this is not possible.

Depending on their construction, the wire-p-wire or wire-n-wire portions may or may not act as just resistors, or as schottky diodes.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, the 'wire-*-wire' terminology really helped this click for me (and led me down a rabbit hole studying electron and hole mobility in metals).

Answer (score 3):

It won't work as a PN junction rectifier, because the rectifying action of such a diode is caused by forming a depletion region at the joint.  Between the N and P materials, you've placed a metal.  Metal is an enormous source of electrons and of holes, that can never become depleted.
What MIGHT happen, is that a semiconductor-metal junction can also be a diode (not P-N, but P-metal or metal-N), in which case the depletion happens in the P or N material only.     Semiconductor-to-metal contact metals are chosen, engineered to be nonrectifying.  Aluminum alloyed to silicon is nonrectifying, aka "ohmic"; platinum against silicon makes a (Schottky barrier) rectifier.

Comment: Interesting tidbit about engineered semi-to-metal connections. Going to need to study some about that.